# how do I clear the Plugin svelte: A11y: on:blur error/warning?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

In svelte if I setup a `<select>` control like this:

```
<select bind:value={selected} on:change="{() => changeTheme()}">
```

the change event fires correctly and the value is bound but I get a warning in vscode:

```
(!) Plugin svelte: A11y: on:blur must be used instead of on:change, unless absolutely necessary and it causes no negative consequences for keyboard only or screen reader users.
```

If I change the binding to `on:blur` as described, the event only works if you click elsewhere in the page after you make your selection (causing the select control to lose focus). `on:click` kind of works, but is annoying.

`on:change` seems correct - how do I clear this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is put a comment above the line with your select element.

`<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-onchange -->`

You will need to reload the window to clear the error. https://svelte.dev/docs#Comments if you're ever curious how to disable a warning in VS code it tells you the name of it after the warning, whatever is in the parenthesis goes after `svelte-ignore`.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the answer and I flagged it as such. However, the `onblur` suggestion is not really suitable for `onchange` - seems like maybe I should file a bug report. Where? With the svelte vscode plugin? or with in the a11y repo? A11y issues seem more accessibility related, not code related...

Comment: It actually will be removed in the next minor version: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/6457